# Updatepanel Leaks Memory in Webpart

Tags: 2010, updatepanel

I've got a very simple visual webpart and I'm trying to figure out why.  In IE9, after about 10 minutes, memory usage has slowly climbed up about 5MB.  If I let it keep running, it'll just keep on using more and more memory.  I've briefly tested this in Chrome and it also seems to eat up memory, but nowhere near as fast.

Here's the page code

```
<asp:ScriptManagerProxy ID="ScriptManagerProxy1" runat="server" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
</Triggers>
<ContentTemplate>     
    <asp:Label ID="label2" runat="server" Font-Size="40pt" />
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and the code behind for the Timer_Tick is just updating the time for the label

```
    protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label2.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
    }
```

It seems like it should be simple.  I've played around with a disposing the UpdatePanel, but that didn't seem to help.  Am I missing something here?  Any suggestions?

Comment: How often is your timer ticking?

Comment: If you are running this in Chrome, run the profiler on it, check the javascript and network, you will be able to see where the memory leak is happening from that. Also this is a common problem with AsyncPostBackTrigger, I have seen in in ASP.Net before in StackExchange. Might be worth looking at that?

Comment: For testing purposes, the timer was ticking every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Jef,

Instead of using Update Panel, you can use Web service with AJAX behaviour as described in this article:
[AJAX Style Web Parts in SharePoint the Easy Way](http://dbremes.wordpress.com/2011/01/03/ajax-style-web-parts-in-sharepoint-the-easy-way/)

He is exactly doing the same thing you are trying... Also for repetitive calls you can use javascript `setTimeout(functionName,1000)`

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'm checking it out.  I don't have much experience with Javascript, but I'm digging through it.